# Pull id's from one table and map into another in MySQL using trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables 'Sample' and 'Results', I want to pull the id's of Sample table and map it into the Results table.

I will put in an example for better understanding,

```
sample_id (Auto increment)     Sample_No      Sample_Name    Experiment_id
     1                           NL-1           ABC             300
     2                           NL-2           XYZ             300
     3                           NL-3           JKL             300

     4                           NL-3           WER             301
```

Now Sample No : NL-1 will have multiple result name and so will the other Sample_Names

```
result_id (Auto increment)     Sample_No      Result_Name    Experiment_id 
     1                           NL-1           abc             300
     2                           NL-2           abc             300
     3                           NL-3           abc             300
     4                           NL-1           xyz             300
     5                           NL-2           xyz             300
     6                           NL-3           xyz             300
     7                           NL-1           jfk             300
     8                           NL-2           jfk             300

     9                           NL-1           abc             301
     10                          NL-1           xyz             301
```

So what I want to do is pull the sample id by comparing it to the Experiment_id and the Result_Name. Something like this.

```
result_id (Auto increment)  **Sample_id**    Sample_No      Result_Name  Experiment_id 
     1                         1            NL-1           abc             300
     2                         1            NL-2           abc             300
     3                         1            NL-3           abc             300
     4                         2            NL-1           xyz             300
     5                         2            NL-2           xyz             300
     6                         2            NL-3           xyz             300
     7                         3            NL-1           jfk             300
     8                         3            NL-2           jfk             300

     9                         4            NL-1           abc             301
     10                        4            NL-1           xyz             301
```

I know how to create a trigger to pull the recent Experiment_id but I have been unable to do this particular task. Please, help me.

```
create trigger SAMPLE_before_insert before insert on SAMPLE FOR EACH ROW 
  set new.Experiment_id = (select max(Experiment_id) from EXPERIMENT);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you expand on your explanation. There seems to be a jump in logic between your stated criteria and that inferred by your query

Comment: this approach feels like phantom reads (race conditions) waiting to happen depening on transaction isolation level offcource..

Comment: @Strawberry the query is just an example I wanted to provide that I created a trigger that pulls the recent Experiment Id from the tables from each entry. But I cannot pull the needed sample ids according to my requirement

Comment: @RaymondNijland Okay do you have any example or a link that I can refer to build this query.